# Transfer c++ executable from desktop linux distribution to a linux board one

Tags: c++, linux, executable, transfer

I'm developing a c++ app in Ubuntu Desktop 16.04. I have created an executable c++ file with eclipse. Furthermore I'm using external libraries like poco and avro which I link dynamically. I need to try my app on a cubietruck that runs on Lubuntu Desktop 12.10. My approach it to install only the desired g++ compiler on Lubuntu because I want to install as less as possible on the board. Then to  transfer there the same folder structure which resides in Ubuntu that contains the executable file as well as the external libraries'.so files and its headers. Since I have almost no experience in boards and transfer between linux distro's is my approach an efficient one?

Comment: The common way to install applications at different linux distros is recompiling the code for the target platform using the system available compiler. E.g. RPM managers like zypper support doing so and manage the dependencies.

Comment: You need to compile on your host computer (the desktop) using a cross-compiler for the target architecture (the board). You don't need to install any compiler on the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is the different architecture. Your board is ARM while your Desktop is x86. Your application needs to be compiled on the board. Also you need to get the library files for arm.

Comment: It does not need to be compiled *on* the board. It can be compiled with a [cross-build environment](http://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/). GCC can be built for a target of `arm-linux-gnueabi` if the board runs a full distro or something like `arm-linux-uclibc` if it has something like Ångstrom on it.

Comment: @greyfade The tutorial I'm following is :http://docs.cubieboard.org/tutorials/ct1/installation/install_lubuntu_desktop_server_to_sd_card. Sorry for my stupid question but if it runs Lubuntu and it omits a compiler, how can it built on board. How are the standard c++ headers going to be retrieved ?

Comment: @greyfade sorry for the question I just find out that cross-build environment was indeed a link. Thanks a lot.